# Emacs mode line minimalist

Tags: mode-line

i have a config for minimalist mode line, its the next;

```
(setq column-number-mode t)
(setq mode-line-percent-position nil)
(setq mode-line-modes
      (mapcar (lambda (elem)
            (pcase elem
              (`(:propertize (,_ minor-mode-alist . ,_)
               . ,_)
               "")
              (t elem)))
          mode-line-modes))
```

and gets the next mode-line output example:

```
U:**- *scratch*      (13,25)    (Lisp Interaction)
```

and my question is how to remove the parentheses for get some:

```
U:**- *scratch*      13,25      Lisp Interaction
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to modify `mode-line-modes` again.  The parens are hard-coded in the default value.  In 27.2 that is:

```el
(defvar mode-line-modes
  (let ((recursive-edit-help-echo "Recursive edit, type C-M-c to get out"))
    (list (propertize "%[" 'help-echo recursive-edit-help-echo)
      "("
      `(:propertize ("" mode-name)
            help-echo "Major mode\n\
mouse-1: Display major mode menu\n\
mouse-2: Show help for major mode\n\
mouse-3: Toggle minor modes"
            mouse-face mode-line-highlight
            local-map ,mode-line-major-mode-keymap)
      '("" mode-line-process)
      `(:propertize ("" minor-mode-alist)
            mouse-face mode-line-highlight
            help-echo "Minor mode\n\
mouse-1: Display minor mode menu\n\
mouse-2: Show help for minor mode\n\
mouse-3: Toggle minor modes"
            local-map ,mode-line-minor-mode-keymap)
      (propertize "%n" 'help-echo "mouse-2: Remove narrowing from buffer"
              'mouse-face 'mode-line-highlight
              'local-map (make-mode-line-mouse-map
                  'mouse-2 #'mode-line-widen))
      ")"
      (propertize "%]" 'help-echo recursive-edit-help-echo)
      " "))
  "Mode line construct for displaying major and minor modes.")
```